# how to send an attachment to user in a Teams chat using Graph api in teams bot framework?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have created this bot for teams using the teams bot framework and i want to let the user download a file when a button is clicked on an adaptive card
[image]

The download button here, when clicked, will call a function that will execute this code:

```
async getInternetAttachment() {
  // NOTE: The contentUrl must be HTTPS.
  return {
      name: 'architecture-resizer.png',
      contentType: 'image/png',
      contentUrl: 'https://dfstudio-d420.kxcdn.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/digital_camera_photo-1080x675.jpg'
  }; }
```

this above code will run as expected and will download the image from the link to the chat, but the problem arises when i try to download a pdf or xlsx file like this,

```
  return {
    name: 'architecture-resizer.pdf',
    contentType: 'application/pdf',
    contentUrl: 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/1l1tjOQfqnNLZObeCaQyXG8WB-wKGE_yQmXTGVKPxwTc/edit?usp=drive_link'
};
```

this will give me the error "[onTurnError] unhandled error: Error: Unknown attachment type"

I tried both these codes for sending the png and pdf file in the bot emulator and it worked perfectly but when i try to use the same code in a bot i created using teams toolkit, it gives me this error i posted above.

and so after some research i found that to get certain file types i need to use a graph api with the file already existing in sharepoint, but i just can't seem to figure it out and would appreciate some help with it.
I tried using an example codejust o understand how it worked and even that is givng me error

the example code i tried :

```
    authProvider,
};

const client = Client.init(options);

const chatMessage = {
    body: {
        contentType: 'html',
        content: 'Here\'s the latest budget. <attachment id=\"153fa47d-18c9-4179-be08-9879815a9f90\"></attachment>'
    },
    attachments: [
        {
            id: '153fa47d-18c9-4179-be08-9879815a9f90',
            contentType: 'reference',
            contentUrl: 'https://m365x987948.sharepoint.com/sites/test/Shared%20Documents/General/test%20doc.docx',
            name: 'Budget.docx'
        }
    ]
};

await client.api('/teams/fbe2bf47-16c8-47cf-b4a5-4b9b187c508b/channels/19:4a95f7d8db4c4e7fae857bcebe0623e6@thread.tacv2/messages')
    .version('beta')
    .post(chatMessage);
```

and this give me the error : "[onTurnError] unhandled error: Error: ContentType of an attachment is not set"

would greatly appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Hello @user9262680  -  Could you please confirm whether you are trying it in Teams Desktop client or Web client? Also, please verify the Content Type configuration and its value.

Comment: hey @ChetanSharma-msft - I am trying this out using teams toolkit by locally hosting it.
I tried it also in Bot framework emulator and it could send the pdf and excel files but the same code is not working when im trying it in the teams toolkit.
i believe the content tye is mentioned in the code i have posted in the question.

Comment: We tried the same HTTP example in Graph explorer. We changed the content url to point to an actual file in our tenant. Could you please confirm if you are using the correct content url? Also can you try the HTTP example in Graph and let us know if you are facing the same issue?

Comment: hey @Meghana-MSFT - Can you share the content url you used and also the request you made in microsoft graph?

Comment: Please find the request body - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmzbf.png. This is contenturl we are using - https://m365x17798679.sharepoint.com/:w:/r/sites/meghanatest/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7BB60C63FE-F665-4BFD-8703-B181B78F529A%7D&file=testdoc.docx

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT - Thanks for that, 
If i had an excel file in a one drive and i want to send that file from a teams bot to the user, how should i go about it?
i would be really helpful bc im a bit confused as to how the process is to send excel files from the bot to the user.

Comment: The files must be in sharepoint to send via Graph.

Comment: oh, from the documentation i was under the impression it could be done from both sharepoint and one drive, is there any documentation or samples about how one can send these files as an attachment  in Teams bot framework using Graph?

Comment: Please refer these documents - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-4-send-a-message-with-file-attachment-in-it,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-files

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, i have done as it is suggested in the documentation .But the attachment is not sent in the chat.
no error or anything as well.
I call the api in a function when the button is pressed.

Comment: Are you using the Graph API? If yes can you try the same using [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) once. Can you also refer this sample if it helps - https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-file-upload

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT Yes, i want to use Graph API because i want to send an excel file from the bot to the user, i understand that Graph API is the only way to do that, just returning it using teams bot API using the content url is not working as it gives the error "[onTurnError] unhandled error: Error: Unknown attachment type".

Also the sample here doesn't appear to be using Graph API , i am building the bot using node js.
Is there any other sample that shows how Graph API can be used to send an excel file from the bot to the user.
Thanks for your help !!

Comment: Unfortunately, we currently do not have a sample that shows how Graph API can be used to send an excel file from the bot to the user. We only have this Graph doc currently - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#example-4-send-a-message-with-file-attachment-in-it

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT ohh understood, but is it right to assume that graph API is the only way to send an excel file from the bot to user in teams bot framework?

Comment: This can be done using bot API as well which we shared earlier - https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-file-upload

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT I have tried this method and it works fine for Image files but when i try to send a PDF file or an excel file, it will give me the error "[onTurnError] unhandled error: Error: Unknown attachment type".
I have described this in detail in the initial post as well.